Randomizing SplashText
I was wondering how to make splash text that randomizes when you click it, because everything I tried doesn't work, and I just simply cant find it anywhere.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Random Text Selector</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="select">Pick text</button>
  <div class="main">
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">please help me fix this</footer>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var idArray = [];
      idArray[0] = "hi";
      idArray[1] = "hello";
      idArray[2] = "SKhfvkhbSVHgjfg";
      idArray[3] = "k";
      idArray[4] = "c'ya";

      var randomParagraph = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = idArray[randomParagraph];
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>



(The code above is a combination of Chat GPT and the only thing I could find on the internet but this doesn't work and it's not changing when I click the text anyway.)

Please read that ChatGPT is banned. However, the example works as presented.

as pointed out the code you shared already fulfills the question you asked close enough to create ambiguity.
